# How to lock whatsapp media files in gallery

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp

I am using whatsapp for a long time and i want to know how i can  lock or hide whatsapp media files (movies, audios,pictures etc) in gallery. Some times my friends sends via whatsapp  videos and pictures (those files auto saves itself in gallery) which i don't want anyone else to see. can you please tell me how to hide or lock whatsapp media settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method or app which allows you to lock your WhatsApp media files or lock WhatsApp directly. There are some apps which claims that they do so. But the fact is that they only prevent any app from opening from the start screen only. You can always access the WhatsApp or any other app directly through app list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's no such way to lock them, unless you have your master lock on for your device.

But you could try this app:

[WhatsApp Locker](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/whatsapp-locker/883e91de-5565-444c-8f50-aa6d09422c3f)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible currently in WP to create secured photos folder. You might want to use some app like [Lock & Hide](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/lock-hide/b74e1e88-4113-41ee-9739-ff69b33c3b66) or [Secure Photo Gallery](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/secure-photo-gallery/7526b41e-d454-49cd-b34d-fceeb020e1c7) which will allow you to import the photos into the app and then you can safely delete them from Photos Hub.